# How to use a same resultset twice in Java

Tags: java, sql

I would like to use **same** result set twice, once is to check whether it is empty and execute code based on the result, and then, using `(resultset.next()` the second result set will always skip a line because of the first result set

Here's my code so far :

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connection);
statement = (Statement) connection.createStatement();
resultset = statement.executeQuery(query);

String id = "0";
String idfromdb;

if(resultset.next() == false){
  System.out.println("table is empty")
  statement.executeUpdate(" INSERT INTO table VALUES ('value') ");
}

else{
  while(resultset.next()){
    idfromdb = resultset.getString("value")
    if(! idfromdb = id){
      System.out.println("no similar data has been found");
    }    
    else{
      System.out.println("similar data has been found");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to [do-while](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) loop:

```
if(resultset.next() == false{
    System.out.println("table is empty")
    statement.executeUpdate(" INSERT INTO table VALUES ('value') ");
} else {
  do  {
    idfromdb = resultset.getString("value")
    if(! idfromdb = id){
        System.out.println("no similar data has been found");
    }

    else{
        System.out.println("similar data has been found");
    }
  } while(resultset.next());
}
```

> do-while evaluates its expression at the bottom of the loop instead of the top.

Comment: but where should i put my (if empty) code at ? after the while ?

Comment: @KevinGuswanto keep it and change inside else statement

Comment: ah, alrighty. so if ( not equal ) , else if ( equal ) , else <- this will do the empty one , is that it ?

Answer (score 2):

When you call `resultset.next()` it will fetch one record,so you need to call **[previous()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#previous())** to reset the cursor

The full code:

```
boolean hasRecord = true;
if(!resultset.next()){// you are missing ) here
    System.out.println("table is empty")
    statement.executeUpdate(" INSERT INTO table VALUES ('value') ");
    hasRecord = false;
}
if(hasRecord){
   resultset.previous();//move to the previous record
}
```

Comment: @KevinGuswanto It is due to your code itself, you are missing `)`,check my updated answer

Comment: no, the auto-completion code doesn't give me .hasNext() option